# Error when building with codeLite in Windows using cygwin64

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, codelite

```
    C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe -j4 -e -f  Makefile"
----------Building project:[ clockType - Debug ]----------
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Debug/clockType.cpp.o', needed by 'Debug/clockType'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Trevor/CSCI_3232/clockType'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Trevor/CSCI_3232/clockType'
make: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
1 errors, 0 warnings
```

I have been getting this error whenever I try to build anything with codelite and cygwin64(g++). Even a simple hello world application that runs fine in the cygwin64 terminal. I assume it is something wrong I am doing with codelite. Thanks for your help. This is my first time dealing with c++ outside of class, have no problems with java and eclipse. I downloaded codelite because it was the first link when I googled c++ ide no idea if it is any good or not.

Comment: How are you compiling your code. Can you mention the command that you are using ?

Comment: just the build button in codelite and in cygwin terminal I'm using 'g++ (filename).cpp'

Comment: If you need anymore info than that let me know. I'm not really sure what your looking for.